# OpenVPN: several static IP's for one certificate / client name

Tags: openvpn

As far there is only one client using a certificate one can set in `server.conf`

```
...
client-config-dir ccd
...
```

and in `ccd/client_name`

```
ifconfig-push static-IP mask=255.255.0.0
route ....
```

to assign a static IP to the client. This works for me.

Now I have 2 clients sharing the same name / certificate. Using dynamical IP it works and both get unique IPs.

But is it possible to assign also static IP to them?

I tried:

```
ifconfig-push static-IP1 static-IP2 mask
```

and

```
ifconfig-push static-IP2/31 mask
```

Comment: Try Solution 2 in [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=8552&start=15).

Comment: I tried `multiple local`in `server.conf`but this is not a valid option.  I saw that the corresponding option to allow several connections with one certificate is `duplicate-cn` in `server.conf` which is activated in my configuration.  Searching for this I [found](https://serverfault.com/questions/1132845/how-to-set-a-static-ip-for-client-on-openvpn-server-with-duplicate-cn) [and](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=7273). As I understand several static IPs for one CN are not possible.